# SQL Server datetime values expressed as UTC with time zone designator

Tags: sql-server

An `Order` table contains `OrderDate` and `OfficeNum` among other columns, while the `Office` table contains the time zone related columns `TimeZone` and `UseDST` besides the `OfficeNum`.

How to express the order date as UTC time value with time zone designator (in SQL Server 2008+)?

```
SELECT OrderNum
      ,ord.OfficeNum
      ,TimeZone
      ,UseDST
      ,OrderDate AS OrderLocalTime
      ,OrderUtcTime = dateadd(hh, -TimeZone + UseDST, OrderDate)
      --need local time expressed as UTC with time zone designator e.g. 2018-08-27T14:45:14-05:00
FROM Orders ord 
JOIN Office ofc ON ord.OfficeNum = ofc.OfficeNum 
WHERE OrderNum = 1
```

There are multiple posts on how to handle TimeZone properly in SQL Server such as https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39421/how-to-handle-timezone-properly-in-sql-server/114628 my problem is that I don't need to convert the current time values at the server based on the server's time zone, but rather express timestamp values saved in the database, knowing 2 parameters: TimeZone as an integer (offset) and UseDST, indicating if Daylight Saving Time was used or not.

Answer (score 0):

TODATETIMEOFFSET function https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-date-functions/sql-server-todatetimeoffset-function/ seems to work!